# Java: Avoid inserting duplicate in arraylist

Tags: java, data-structures

I am novice to java. I have an `ArrayList` and I want to avoid duplicates on insertion. My `ArrayList` is

```
ArrayList<kar> karList = new ArrayList<kar>();
```

and the the field I want to check is :

```
 kar.getinsertkar().
```

I have read that I can use `HashSet` or `HashMap` but I have no clue.

Comment: "but i have no clue" What do you mean? Use a `HashSet`, just like you've read.

Comment: [clue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html)

Comment: Note that there's no rule that says you can't have *both* an `ArrayList` and a `HashSet` with the same elements.  You can use an `ArrayList` to keep the elements in the order you want, and a `HashSet` to check whether an element is already present.  (The check will be quicker than searching the `ArrayList`, but maintaining two collections will slow things down.)  Sometimes this is the right way to do things.

Answer (score 30):

Whenever you want to prevent duplicates, you want to use a `Set`.

In this case, a HashSet would be just fine for you.

```
HashSet karSet = new HashSet();
karSet.add(foo);
karSet.add(bar);
karSet.add(foo);
System.out.println(karSet.size());
//Output is 2
```

For completeness, I would also suggest you use the generic (parameterized) version of the class, assuming Java 5 or higher.

```
HashSet<String> stringSet = new HashSet<String>();
HashSet<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
...etc...
```

This will give you some type safety as well for getting items in and out of your set.

Comment: Also usually we use interface for vars type: `Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<String>();` not the implementation

Answer (score 12):

A set is simply a collection that can contain no duplicates so it sounds perfect for you.

It is also very simple to implement. For example:

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>();
```

This would provide you a set that can hold Objects of type String.

To add to the set is just as simple:

```
mySet.add("My first entry!");
```

By definition of a set, you can add whatever you want and never run into a duplicate.

Have fun!

**EDIT :** If you decide you are dead-set on using an ArrayList, it is simple to see if an object is already in the list before adding it. For example:

```
public void addToList(String newEntry){
    if(!myList.contains(newEntry))
        myList.add(newEntry);
}
```

Note: All my examples assume you are using String objects but they can easily be swapped to any other Object type.

Answer (score 8):

Use a `HashSet` instead of an `ArrayList`. But, to really make the `HashSet` really work well, you must override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of the class/objects that are inserted into the `HashSet`.

Foe example:

```
 Set<MyObject> set = new HashSet<MyObject>();
 set.add(foo);
 set.add(bar);

 public class MyObject {
     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object obj) {
         if (obj instanceof MyObject)
             return (this.id = obj.id) 
         else
             return false;
     }
     // now override hashCode()
}
```

Please see the following [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html) for overriding `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: I used arraylist all over in my class for other methods, how can i change it?

Comment: +1 good suggestion, and we could point out that the objects going into the set should have a proper equals() and hashCode() method implemented.

Comment: The methods used in a HashSet should be the same as an ArrayList because they both implement the same interface.

Comment: @blackpanther No, `ArrayList` has methods that `HashSet` and `LinkedHashSet` don't have, particularly `get(int index)`.  We don't know how important it is to have those methods available.

Comment: @ajb my bad. I forgot about that.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `LinkedHashSet`, to avoid duplicated elements and keep the insertion order.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use any `Set` implementation, e.g you can use `HashSet`.
If you want to `add` custom object `kar` into your `HashSet`, you need to `override` `equals` and `hashcode` method.
You can read more about `equals` and `hashcode`, [see](http://www.jchq.net/certkey/0902certkey.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement own List which extends LinkedList and override its add methods:

1. public boolean add(E e)
2. public void add(int index, E element)
3. public boolean addAll(Collection collection)
4. public boolean addAll(int index, Collection collection)

Answer (score 0):

An example removing repeated Strings in an ArrayList:

```java
var list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
        "hello",
        "java",
        "test",
        "hello"
));

System.out.println(list);

System.out.println(new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(list)));
```

Output:

```
[hello, java, test, hello]
[java, test, hello]
```