# Sorted list of contacts having duplicates ,why?

Tags: android, sorting, android-contacts, android-cursor

I have sorted and listed my phone contacts in to an arraylist but ,i got many duplicates of same contact names in the list .How this happens? how to avoid this?

This is what i have tried,

```
  cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                "(" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");

  while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        try {

            name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            phonenumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            contact_names_list.add(name);
            phone_num_list.add(phonenumber);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

can anyone help??

Comment: you can use `HASHSET`

Comment: any example please?

Comment: Are the contacts in more than one group? For example, on the SIM and in Google Contacts.

Comment: yeah some contacts are in one group , but not all contacts , here i am getting more than 2 duplicates of each contact name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No one here seems to answer your question.

The reason you're seeing duplicate contacts is that you're querying for **phones** not **contacts**.

In Android there are 3 main tables:

1. `Contacts` table - has one item per contact
2. `RawContacts` table - has one item per-contact per-account (such as Google, Outlook, Whatsapp, etc.) - multiple `RawContacts` are linked to a single `Contact`
3. `Data` table - has one item per detail (name, email, phone, address, etc.) - each data item is linked to a single `RawContact`, and multiple `Data` rows are linked to each `RawContact`.

You're querying on `CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` which is a part of the `Data` table, so if a contact has more then one phone, and/or it has the same phone from multiple sources (e.g. Google and Whatsapp) you'll get the same phone with the same `CONTACT_ID` more then once.

The solution would be, to use a `HashMap` (rather then a `HashSet`), where the key is `CONTACT_ID`, so you can display multiple phones per contact:

```
String[] projection = new String[] { CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID, CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);

HashMap<Long, Contact> contacts = new HashMap<>();

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cursor.getLong(0);
    String name = cursor.getString(1);
    String phone = cursor.getString(2);

    Contact c = contacts.get(id);
    if (c == null) {
        // newly found contact, add to Map
        c = new Contact();
        c.name = name;
        contacts.put(id, c);
    }

    // add phone to contact class
    c.phones.add(phone);
}
cursor.close();


// simple class to store multiple phones per contact
private class Contact {
    public String name;
    // use can use a HashSet here to avoid duplicate phones per contact
    public List<String> phones = new ArrayList<>(); 
}
```

**If you want to sort your HashMap by name:**

```
List<Contact> values = new ArrayList<>(contacts.values());
Collections.sort(values, new Comparator<Contact> {
    public int compare(Contact a, Contact b) {
        return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
    }
});

// iterate the sorted list, per contact:
for (Contact contact : values) {
    Log.i(TAG, "contact " + contact.name + ": ");
    // iterate the list of phones within each contact:
    for (String phone : contact.phones) {
        Log.i(TAG, "\t phone: " + phone);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have done a great job , this one is the perfect solution to my problem .Thanks for the support

Comment: How can i get a sorted list, i have tried treemap but it is not properly sorted

Comment: you can get just the values, as an ArrayList, from the HashMap, and then sort that ArrayList, see my update

Comment: hai when i sort like this, how can i get phone numbers corresponding to each contacts in correct order ?

Comment: :can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can try with [**`HashSet`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

> public class HashSet  extends AbstractSet implements Set,
>   Cloneable, Serializable

- **<s>Duplicate</s>** values are not allowed.

**Code Structure**

```
 HashSet<String> hashSET = new HashSet<String>();
        hashSET.add("AA");
        hashSET.add("BB");
        hashSET.add("CC");
        hashSET.add("AA"); // Adding duplicate elements
```

**Then**

```
Iterator<String> j = hashSET.iterator();
        while (j.hasNext())
            System.out.println(j.next()); // Will print "AA" once.
    }
```

Now **`SORT`** your **`Hashset`** Values using [**`TreeSet`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

> TreeSet implements the **SortedSet** interface so duplicate values are not
>   allowed.

```
 TreeSet<String> _treeSET= new TreeSet<String>(hashSET);
```

Comment: Thank you , but can you explain how this happen? i mean the duplicate values ??

Comment: @Gibs No coming from SIM and MOBILE. (Google contacts also)

Comment: @Gibs Solved this yet?

Comment: Thank you it works ,but i lost the sorted order of the list

Comment: Now i have an unsorted list of contacts ,so i couldn't identify the contact number for each contact

Comment: @Gibs use `TreeSet`

Comment: Ok thank you i will try it , and i am accepting your answer because it solved the duplicate issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161156/discussion-between-gibs-and-intellij-amiya).

Answer (score 2):

May be in your contacts having multiple groups, and that group will be a WhatsApp,Google etc..Go to your contacts and search **that contact having whatsApp** account. will showing double entry with different **Group**

you should use or change your `ContactsBean` , in your `Bean` use `HashSet`

> **Note:** `HashSet` can avoid duplicate entry **[more](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-hashset)**
>
> `HashSet` contains unique elements only,it can avoid same key element form `HashSet`

**Example** bean

```
public class ContactBean {
    private HashSet<String> number = new HashSet<String>(); 

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        if (number == null)
            return; 
        this.number.add(number.trim()); 
    }

    public HashSet<String> getNumber() {
        return this.number; 
    }
}
```

**Simple Example**

```
//Creating HashSet and adding elements  
  
  HashSet<String> hashSet=new HashSet<String>();  
  hashSet.add("Dhruv");  
  hashSet.add("Akash");  
  hashSet.add("Dhruv");   //Avoiding this entry   
  hashSet.add("Nirmal");  

 //Traversing elements  
 
  Iterator<String> itr = hashSet.iterator();  
  while(itr.hasNext()){  
   System.out.println(itr.next());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HashSet` for avoid duplication:-

```
HashSet<String> hset = 
               new HashSet<String>();
```

you can add like `ArrayList` in `HashSet`:-

```
hset.add(your_string);
```

OR

Convert your `ArrayList` to `HashSet` :-

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(your_arraylist_object);
```

`HashSet` avoid Duplicate Entry :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my question is how to avoid the duplicates when sorting , any help?

Comment: convert your arraylist into hashset after sorting :)

Comment: check updated answer that remove duplicate from arraylist :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why are you getting duplicate items from contacts, maybe phone contacts already have duplicate values.You can check that in Contacts app.

You should always use set data structure wherever you want to avoid duplicate items. You can find the better explanation and example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19013920/8979298).

Answer (score 0):

I think your duplication is because of Whatsapp contact interfering with contact . so you can use something like this

```
                      String lastPhoneName = "";
                     String lastPhoneNumber = "";

                    //IN YOUR CONTACT FETCHING WHILE LOOP , INSIDE TRY 
                   String contactName = c.getString(c
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String phNumber = c
                            .getString(c
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    if (!contactName.equalsIgnoreCase(lastPhoneName) && !phNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(lastPhoneNumber)) {

                        lastPhoneName = contactName;
                        lastPhoneNumber = phNumber;

                        ContactModel model = new ContactModel();
                        model.setContact_id(contactid);
                        model.setContact_name(contactName.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
                        model.setContact_number(phNumber.replaceAll("\\D+", ""));


                        list_contact_model.add(model);

                    }
```

this will check that previous number is same as old one than skip it . I hope You get your answer

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` add items in key/value pair and also remove duplicate entry from item set.

```
List<String> phone_num_list= new ArrayList<>();
// add elements to phone_num_list, including duplicates
Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
hs.addAll(phone_num_list);
phone_num_list.clear();
phone_num_list.addAll(hs);
```

Happy coding!!