# How to not add duplicate items to an array list

Tags: java, android

**EDITED**
I didn't explain myself properly, so I'll ask again properly.

I have array list of json object.
My json contain 13000 objects , each object contains a few values.
In some cases, one of the values in the objects is the same. For example:

That what i have now:

```
public void readData() {
        String json_string = null;

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getActivity().getAssets().open("garages.json");
            int size = inputStream.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            inputStream.read(buffer);
            inputStream.close();

            json_string = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            garage = gson.fromJson(json_string, Garage.class);

//In this loop I'm checking address and if it equal to current user address , I'm add this object to Array list.

            for (int i = 0; i < 13476; i++) {
                if (garage.getGarage().get(i).garageCity.equals(AddressSingleton.getInstance().getCurrentAddress())) {
                    garageObjects.add(garage.getGarage().get(i));
                    Log.d("TheDataIS", "readData: " + garage.getGarage().get(i).garageName);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If you look at the JSON file, you can see that the name in the first and second garage is the same, but another value **garage_code** is different.
In this case I do not want to add both objects to the array.

```
{
"garage" : [
 {
   "garage_code":16,
"garage_name": "New York Garage",
"phone_number": "123123",
"city":"New York"
 },{
   "garage_code":21,
"garage_name": "New York Garage",
"phone_number": "123123",
"city":"New York"
 },{
   "garage_code":51,
"garage_name": "My Garage",
"phone_number": "089898",
"city":"Some city"
 },...
```

For this json file , i want that only the first and third objects will be added to the Array.

Comment: Why use `ArrayList`? Use `Set` to avoid duplicates.

Comment: I think that this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19013920/2972052

Comment: there is a special collection type for the items that should not be duplicates: called `Set`.  But for it to detect the duplicates, objects in it have to correctly inmplement `exuals()` and `hashCode()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Array, Finding Duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951547/java-array-finding-duplicates)

Comment: it'll help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/17812555

Answer (score 0):

Agree with all above answers. You need to use Set instead of List.

Along with Set you may need to override **equals and hashcode** in Object in Garage for **given parameter**.

**For example** :- If your requirement is Garage name shouldn't duplicate, then override equals and hashcode with garage name param

Answer (score 0):

Pass your array list to (set) this collection contains no duplicates

```
set<type>  garageSet = new Hashset<type>(garage.getGarage());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah if you need a collection to not store duplicate items, I'd suggest better use `HashSet`, but incase you need to preserve the order use `LinkedHashSet`.

**But** if you wish to use array list then you can wrap the old list into a set to remove duplicates and wrap that set in a list again. ex :

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(arraylist));
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it in another way.
In garage object class I overrided equals method:

```
@Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            GarageObject that = (GarageObject) o;
            return garageNumber == that.garageNumber;
        }
```

Than in fragment class I added additional if condition :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 13273; i++) {
                if (garage.getGarage().get(i).garageCity.equals(AddressSingleton.getInstance().getCurrentAddress())) {
                    if (!garageObjects.contains(garage.getGarage().get(i))) {
                        garageObjects.add(garage.getGarage().get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Not it works good.